# How to assign and then use a variable in a list of algebraic equations

Tags: calc

In a Calc algebraic expression I would like to do something like this:

```
[r := 3, 2 * r] =>
```

and get a result something like this:

```
[r := 3, 2 * r] =>[3, 6]
```

What I actually get is this:

```
[r := 3, 2 * r] => [r := 3, 32.4e3]
```

because the variable `r` was defined to be 16.2e3 before I entered the algebraic expression.

How should I modify the algebraic expression to get the desired result?  I suppose it could be done with keyboard macros.  Can it be done with a simple algebraic expression?

Comment: No answers so far.  Is it impossible, or is it just that the right person hasn't yet read my question?